# how to pass a properties file/file while configuring spark submit in Azure databricks

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I am trying to pass properties file while configuring spark submit in json format .
It is throwing issue like no such file.

Error: Invalid properties file 'dbfs:/FileStore/tables/conf/properties.conf'.

Json format spark submit :

["--class","com.example.extract.temp","--properties-file","dbfs:/FileStore/tables/conf/properties.conf","dbfs:/FileStore/tables/jars/example.jar"]

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the file name as /dbfs/FileStore/tables/conf/properties.conf